# JavaScript: generate new window (window.open)

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a new window using a function. Everything looks fine to me, but it doesn't work in any of my browsers. I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Please help me to make it work.

```
<script>
var newWin();
function openWin() {
    var features = "toolbar=yes,locationbar=1,directories=1,statusbar=1,menubar=1,scrollbar=1,resizable=yes,titlebar=1";
    newWin = window.open("", "newWin", features);
    var topDoc = "<html><head><title>Dynamic window and document</title></head>";
    var endDoc = "</body></html>";

    newWin.document.write(topDoc, "<body>");
    newWin.document.write("<h1>Dynamic created Window and Document</h1>");
    newWin.document.write("<p><a href='javascript: opener.focus();'>Click here to put the other window on top</a></p>");

    newWin.document.write("<p><a href='javascript: AAAAAA'>Click here to close the other window</a></p>");
    newWin.document.write("<p><input type='button' onclick='self.print();' value='Send the content of this window to a printer'></p>");

    newWin.document.write("<p><input type='button' onclick='BBBBBB' value='Close this window'></p>");

    newWin.document.write(endDoc);

    newWin.document.close();
}

</script>

<p><a href="javascript: openWin();">Click to open a new window</a></p>

    <p><a href="#" onclick="newWin.focus();">Click to put the new window on top</a></p>

    <p><a href="#" onclick="newWin.close();">Click to close the new window</a></p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<p><a href="javascript:{ openWin();}">Click to open a new window</a></p>

    <p><a href="#" onclick="javascript:{newWin.focus();}">Click to put the new window on top</a></p>

    <p><a href="#" onclick="javascript:{newWin.close();}">Click to close the new window</a></p>
```

and change

```
var newWin();
```

to `var newWin;`